# Как получить множество строк из одной таблицы для каждой строки из другой?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Есть таблица с объявлениями, для каждого объявления есть несколько категорий, все категории хранятся в одной таблице. У таблицы объявлений и категорий есть связующая. Как получить нужные объявления и категории к ним в один запрос?

К примеру:

```
Таблица объявлений Ads содержит поля:
id
title
...

Таблица категорий Categories:
id
title
parent_id

Таблица связующая Ads_categories:
id
ads_id
categories_id
```

Максимум, чего я добился: выбирается объявление с одной категорией, и дублируются, пока не выведет остальные категории этого объявления, и так для каждого объявления.

Дополнение.
Я использовал join, и мой запрос похож на тот, что написал товарищ ниже, и вот что я получаю:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ads] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [title] => Продам гараж
                [description] => ...
                [cities_id] => 468
                [users_id] => 12
                [price] => 120000
                [datetime] => 2016-01-31 04:12:07
            )

        [ads_categories] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [ads_id] => 3
                [categories_id] => 2
            )

        [categories] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [title] => Недвижимость
                [parent_id] => 0
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ads] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [title] => Продам гараж
                [description] => ...
                [cities_id] => 468
                [users_id] => 12
                [price] => 120000
                [datetime] => 2016-01-31 04:12:07
            )

        [ads_categories] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [ads_id] => 3
                [categories_id] => 16
            )

        [categories] => Array
            (
                [id] => 16
                [title] => Квартиры
                [parent_id] => 2
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [ads] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [title] => Продам гараж
                [description] => ...
                [cities_id] => 468
                [users_id] => 12
                [price] => 120000
                [datetime] => 2016-01-31 04:12:07
            )

        [ads_categories] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [ads_id] => 3
                [categories_id] => 101
            )

        [categories] => Array
            (
                [id] => 101
                [title] => Куплю
                [parent_id] => 16
            )

    )

)
```

Вот меня интересует, можно ли получить один массив Ads в котором будут сразу все три категории?

Comment: а в каком виде вы хотите получить *категории к ним* - id или названия?

Comment: и айди и названия, но чтобы все категории были в одном массиве с информацией об объявлении

Comment: можно собрать в php? преобразовав массив, можно использовать `group_concat` и `group by`, чтобы получить список категорий.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно изучить использование оператора [join](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) Для вашего случая запрос будет выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Ads
  LEFT JOIN Ads_categories ON ads_id=Ads.id
  LEFT JOIN Categories ON Categories.id=categories_id
WHERE 
  categories_id=X
```

Comment: Да, я использовал join и мой запрос практически аналогичен вашему. У меня не выходит как-то скомпоновать, чтобы в массиве об объявлении были сразу все три категории, а не три массива объявления по одной категории.

Comment: тогда вместо ```where...``` используйте ```groupBy categories_id```